# My SQL Server subquery is always returning NULL

Tags: sql-server, null, subquery

I have a table "Representantes" with a field "Allow Nulls" called "Complemento". 
The issue is that the subquery always return null when "Complemento" is null or empty but when "Complemento" has any value the subquery works perfectly.

Look at my code.

Please.

```
`USE [Realb_DB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CadastrarRepresentante]    Script Date: 01/12/2015 19:54:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CadastrarRepresentante]
    @RazaoSocial nvarchar(100),
    @Nome_Fantasia nvarchar(100),
    @CNPJ nvarchar(50), 
    @Gestor_Responsavel nvarchar(100),
    @RG_Gestor nvarchar(25),
    @CPF_Gestor nvarchar(25),

    @Logradouro nvarchar(100),
    @Bairro nvarchar(100),
    @Numero nvarchar(100),
    @Complemento nvarchar(100) = null,
    @Municipio nvarchar(100),
    @Estado nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

EXEC dbo.cadastrarEndereco @Logradouro = @Logradouro , @Bairro = @Bairro , @Numero = @Numero , 
@Complemento = @Complemento , @Municipio = @Municipio , @Estado = @Estado ;

        WITH CTE_ENDERECO2(ID_Endereco)
        AS (SELECT TOP 1 ID_Endereco FROM dbo.Tabela_Endereco 
        WHERE Logradouro = @Logradouro AND Bairro = @Bairro AND Numero = @Numero
        AND Complemento = @Complemento AND Municipio = @Municipio AND Estado = @Estado ) 

        INSERT INTO Tabela_Representante(Razao_Social, Nome_Fantasia, CNPJ, Gestor_Responsavel, RG_Gestor, CPF_Gestor, FK_Endereco) VALUES(@RazaoSocial,@Nome_Fantasia,@CNPJ,@Gestor_Responsavel,@RG_Gestor,@CPF_Gestor,(SELECT ID_Endereco FROM CTE_ENDERECO2)) 

END`
```

Error message.

[image]

How would I fix it?

Comment: You should post your error message **as text** and you should translate it to English so that most of us can understand it ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following as per your requirements for the subquery:

**Option 1** : Use IFNULL and use 0 or any other number if it is null for comparison.

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID_Endereco FROM dbo.Tabela_Endereco 
        WHERE Logradouro = @Logradouro AND Bairro = @Bairro AND Numero = @Numero
        AND IFNULL(Complemento, 0) = @Complemento AND Municipio = @Municipio AND Estado = @Estado
```

**Option 2:** Add extra check for NULL values in this column

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID_Endereco FROM dbo.Tabela_Endereco 
        WHERE Logradouro = @Logradouro AND Bairro = @Bairro AND Numero = @Numero
        AND (Complemento = @Complemento OR Complemento is null) AND Municipio = @Municipio AND Estado = @Estado
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I'm gonna try it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use for **SQL: `ISNULL(COLUMN_NAME, VALUE)`** and for
**MYSQL: `IFNULL(COLUMN_NAME, VALUE)`** if you are passing blank value as parameter to this procedure. So it will check if there is blank in in column it will convert it into a blank.

Try like this in your case

```
(SELECT TOP 1 ID_Endereco FROM dbo.Tabela_Endereco 
        WHERE Logradouro = @Logradouro AND Bairro = @Bairro AND Numero = @Numero
        AND IFNULL(Complemento, '') = @Complemento AND Municipio = @Municipio AND Estado = @Estado )
```

Comment: I believe according to you my ans is correct, so do approve it. :)